# BitmapSource in xamarin.forms?

Tags: c#, wpf, xamarin.forms, bitmap

I've used before BitmapSource in WPF and I need to use the same codes in Xamarin.Forms.

I'm trying `using System.Windows.Media.Imaging`
but it doesn't exist in `Xamarin.Forms` what should I use to BitmapSource in `Xamarin.Forms`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.imagesource?view=xamarin-forms Btw, why do you need it?

Comment: Xamarin.Forms does not provide the class like `BitmapSource ` , only `ImageSource ` is supported.